# Rubocop cyclomatic complexity of top-level code

Tags: ruby, rubocop, cyclomatic-complexity

Is there a reason why rubocop excludes top-level code when evaluating cyclomatic complexity? It only returns complexity for code independent paths through a method. Is there a way to include top-level code in this analysis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most complexity measures use `def` as a scope.

It is assumed that code at top-level is meant to run only when the app/library is loaded and that all the actual code is within method definitions.

A file that does 30 `require_relative` would bust most metrics, but it is not considered an issue.

Consider moving the actual code you are running in a method and calling it from the top level directly as first improvement.